# Sql request to join book table to many authors to many tags to many category

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, duplicates, many-to-many

I'm creating an online bookstore.

I've create a table book.
I've create another table auteur with à table to join book_author.

AND I've create à table tags. With a table book_tags.

AND I've create a table thema, with a table book_thema.

I dont know how to request select books with all authors of the book in one column, all tags of the book in one column, all thema of the book in one column Without duplicate.

My first try with only joining book and author table

```
select l.livreisbn, l.livretitre, string_agg(a.auteurnom, ', ') as authors
from livre l
left join auteur_livre al on al.livreisbn = l.livreisbn
left join auteur a on a.auteurcode = al.auteurcode
group by l.livreisbn
```

it's working fine

i've this result

```
"0134685991";"Effective Java";"Bloch"
"0134177304";"Core Java Volume I – Fundamentals";"Horstmann"
"2743615871";"Le dahlia noir";"Ellroy"
"2757872117";"La griffe du chien";"Winslow"
"0596009205";"Head First Java";"Sierra, Bates"
"1033903697";"La frontière";"Winslow"
"0672324536";"Data Structures and Algorithms in Java";"Lafore"
"0132350884";"Clean Code";"Martin"
"2253033138";"Le Nom de la rose";"Eco"
"2290349670";"Cosmopolis";"DeLillo"
"0134694726";"Core Java SE 9 for the Impatient";"Horstmann"
"1119527077";"SQL for Dummies";"Taylor"
"2869305922";"White jazz";"Ellroy"
"2742731107";"Libra";"DeLillo"
"2818503094";"La vie liquide";"Bauman"
"1449358457";"Java Performance: The Definite Guide";"Oaks"
"2742726530";"Americana";"DeLillo"
"2021213157";"Cartel";"Winslow"
"1617291999";"Java 8 in Action";"Mycroft, Fusco"
"2264028815";"Ubik";"Dick"
"0131872486";"Thinking in Java";"Eckel"
"0735605176";"Inside Microsoft SQL Server";"Soukup, Delaney"
"2253059498";"Le Pendule de Foucault";"Eco"
"0134540566";"Scala for the Impatient";"Horstmann"
"2743648893";"La tempête qui vient";"Ellroy"
"2869304673";"Le Grand Nulle part";"Ellroy"
"1449358624";"Learning Spark";"Karau, Kowinski, Zaharia, Wendell"
"225394209X";"De superman au surhomme";"Eco"
"11111111";"Java pour les neuneux";"Ait Khelifa"
"2742788392";"L'homme qui tombe";"DeLillo"
"2743602680";"L.A. Confidential";"Ellroy"
"0321349606";"Java concurrency in practice";"Bloch, Goetz, Peierls, Bowbeer, Holmes, Lea"
```

It's perfect. Exactly what I want. But when I try to join other tables in the same way ...

```
select l.livreisbn, l.livretitre, string_agg(a.auteurnom, ', '),string_agg(m.motcledesign, ', ') as keywords, string_agg(sst.sousthemelibelle, ', ') as thema
from livre l
left join auteur_livre al on al.livreisbn = l.livreisbn
left join auteur a on a.auteurcode = al.auteurcode
left join motcle_livre ml on ml.livreisbn = l.livreisbn
left join motcle m on m.motcleid = ml.motcleid
left join soustheme_livre stl on stl.livreisbn = l.livreisbn
left join soustheme sst on sst.sousthemecode = stl.sousthemecode
group by l.livreisbn
```

The result is horrible, with many duplicates items

```
"0134177304";"Core Java Volume I – Fundamentals";"Horstmann, Horstmann, Horstmann, Horstmann, Horstmann, Horstmann, Horstmann";"Informatique, programmation, developpement, conception, java, sql, j2ee";"Programmation JAVA, Programmation JAVA, Programmation JAVA, Programmation JAVA, Programmation JAVA, Programmation JAVA, Programmation JAVA"
"2743615871";"Le dahlia noir";"Ellroy, Ellroy";"noir, polar";""
"2757872117";"La griffe du chien";"Winslow";"";""
"0596009205";"Head First Java";"Sierra, Bates, Sierra, Bates, Sierra, Bates, Sierra, Bates, Sierra, Bates, Sierra, Bates, Sierra, Bates";"Informatique, Informatique, programmation, programmation, developpement, developpement, conception, conception, java, java, sql, sql, j2ee, j2ee";"Programmation JAVA, Programmation JAVA, Programmation JAVA, Programmation JAVA, Programmation JAVA, Programmation JAVA, Programmation JAVA, Programmation JAVA, Programmation JAVA, Programmation JAVA, Programmation JAVA, Programmation JAVA, Programmation JA (...)"
```

I dont how to do that Without duplicate records.

Many thanx.

Comment: I use the function string_agg. "select b.isbn, b.title, string_agg(à.

Comment: I've updated my original post with more details and samples codes. Tnax and Happy new year.

Comment: Happy new year too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`distinct` keyword might be added within `string_agg()` function to return distinctly listed comma-seperated elements, add an order by in the alphabetical order for the column within the function and alias all those function-generated columns respectively :

```
select l.livreisbn, l.livretitre, 
       string_agg(distinct a.auteurnom, ', ' order by l.auteurnom) as auteurnom,
       string_agg(distinct m.motcledesign, ', ' order by m.motcledesign) as keywords, 
       string_agg(distinct sst.sousthemelibelle, ', ' order by sst.sousthemelibelle) as thema
  from livre l
  left join auteur_livre al on al.livreisbn = l.livreisbn
  left join auteur a on a.auteurcode = al.auteurcode
  left join motcle_livre ml on ml.livreisbn = l.livreisbn
  left join motcle m on m.motcleid = ml.motcleid
  left join soustheme_livre stl on stl.livreisbn = l.livreisbn
  left join soustheme sst on sst.sousthemecode = stl.sousthemecode
 group by l.livreisbn, l.livretitre;
```

Comment: It's working fine. Many Thanx and Happy new Year. PS : I'm using postfres but it's not working with MS SQL server ?